# Explain usage of put statement

Tags: sas

```
  data _null_;
   %let _EFIRR_=0;
    %let _EFIREC_=0;

  file '/home/abc/demo/sale.csv' delimiter=',' DSD;
      put country=;
       run;
```

I wrote this code but couldn't find anything in the log. Shouldn't I be getting country=xyz in the log?

Comment: You have a file statement.  PUT write to FILE.  Maybe you want PUTLOG or FILE LOG;  Plus country never gets a value.

Comment: No you shouldn't, you never provided any data to the data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FILE` statement is used to write out to files. I believe you were attempting to read country values *from* the file instead.

You need the `INFILE` statement:

```
data _null_;
  %let _EFIRR_=0;
  %let _EFIREC_=0;

  /* infile statement points to the file which is being read */
  infile '/home/abc/demo/sale.csv' delimiter=',' DSD;

  /* Input statement specifies which columns to populate from the file */
  input country $;

  /* A put statement in a data step without an associated */
  /* file statement will output lines in the log */
  put country=;
run;
```